# MS Access - Not Like <Table of keywords>

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter

I've got a list of customers in MS Access and want to filter them.
There are several keywords that must not be contained in the Name-field of the customer.

So, if the "Name" of a customer contains words like "Ltd." or "Company" they shall not be selected.

The forbidden keywords are listed in another Access-table named "Keywords".

Is it possible to tell the query to select all customers EXCEPT for those, who have a name containing a keyword from the Keywords-table?

Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `not exists` clause.  The following shows the logic using `like`:

```
select c.*
from customers as c
where not exists (select 1
                  from keywords as k
                  where c.name like "*"&k.word&"*"
                 );
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that Access allows string concatenation for the pattern in the `like` (it has lots of strange variations from other databases).  If this doesn't work, the basic idea will.

If `like` doesn't work, you can use `instr()`:

```
select c.*
from customers as c
where not exists (select 1
                  from keywords as k
                  where instr(c.name, k.word) > 0
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instr to search key in company name. Here is sample query.

```
SELECT myCompany.CompanyID, myCompany.CompanyName
FROM myCompany, tblkey
where INSTR(myCompany.CompanyName , tblKey.key_name)=0;
```